# how to delete segments of a sound?

Tags: java, audio, wav, cut, audioinputstream

I have created a program for analyze a file.wav inserted in input. I want to know if I can remove the intervals of time from the original file.wav.
I would cut a parts of the sound unnecessary for the analysis that fall within a definite time. After the elimination of these parts of the sound, I would get a new continuous sound that merge together all parties of sound not eliminated. 
it's possible? 
can you help me?

Comment: what is your attempt so far

Answer (score 1):

Once you have read in your WAV format file, parsed the header, and parked the audio curve data points into some data structure, you have two choices.

- update in place ( trickier to implement )
- copy good data points into a new data structure ( lets do this )

Nice aspect of WAV format is its PCM  which means the audio curve is represented as discrete points on that curve.  Assure you have identified the bit depth which will be available in the header.  A typical bit depth would be 16 bits meaning each sample will consume two bytes of data in your memory buffer.  Print out 100 or so sample values to confirm you have at hand the samples in correct format.  If 16 bits then range of possible values will map to  2^16 distinct integer values.  Whether you have signed or unsigned is important when you examine these sample values.

As a stepping stone I would first get some code working which simply reads in a WAV file and copies each byte into an output file.  Confirm you can play this new output WAV file.  Next write similar code except this time parse the header, identify the sample rate field, update its value from say 44100 to 22050, output the header with this update followed by audio data bytes which appear in the WAV file just after the header.  Play this WAV file, did it speed up or slow down the audio track ?

When you open up the input WAV file and read in each byte, after the header bytes, get working ability to combine two bytes into a single 16 bit integer variable (if your header says you have 16 bit samples).  Each audio sample will consume multiple bytes (8 bit audio sounds horrendous).  So if you have 24 bit audio of course each audio sample in a given channel will span three bytes of your file. Be aware of concept of big and little endianness (do your two bytes appear left to right or right to left).   For simplicity first get working a mono channel input WAV file.  Stereo (2 channel) or X channels are possible in WAV format yet mono is easier.

Lets say we have 10 samples (each a 16 bit integer)

- 0 - 3 good
- 4 - 7 bad  (we will discard these)
- 8 - 9 good

So output file will contain just what remains after ignoring the bad samples 4 - 7 so it will have just 6 samples.

loop across all samples -> identify whether current sample is good -> only copy good sample into output data structure

```
int out_index = 0;

int bit_depth = 16;   // get this 16 from header, could be 24 for example

// how many bytes in bit depth, 2 if 16 bit, 3 if 24 bit
int incr_index = bit_depth / 8;

for (int in_index = 0; in_index < size; in_index += incr_index) {

    if (is_sample_good(in_index)) { //  is this sample good or bad

        output_data[out_index]     = input_data[in_index];
        output_data[out_index + 1] = input_data[in_index + 1];

        out_index += incr_index; 
    }
}
```

Notice in this code the input and output data structures each have their own index ... important since we only advance the output index on good samples

The WAV format file header is always the first X number of bytes of the WAV file (32 bytes if I remember correctly).  In this header is an indicator of total data size.  Keep track of the number of good samples which will drive the value of this data length header tag which you will put into the header section of your output WAV file.   After iterating across your input file and generating your output data structure (memory buffer), then open up your new output file, write into this file your new header with updated value for length tag, then write your new memory buffer, close the file and play it.

Here are some WAV format links

http://unusedino.de/ec64/technical/formats/wav.html

https://www.gamedev.net/resources/_/technical/game-programming/loading-a-wave-file-r709

http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html

http://www.topherlee.com/software/pcm-tut-wavformat.html

http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/audio/javaWavFiles.html

http://www.drdobbs.com/database/inside-the-riff-specification/184409308

Comment: thanks,  I understand. You may still indicate some links useful for this purpose?